# rule changing in bounded wildcards in java-8?

Tags: generics, java-8, typechecking, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

I was following a tutorial about generics in Java defining this static method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(T a) { ... }
```

and saying that

```
min(new GregorianCalendar());
```

couldn't compile because `GregorianCalendar extends Calendar` and `Calendar implements Comparable<Calendar>` so it implied that `GregorianCalendar implements Comparable<Calendar>` and NOT `Comparable<GregorianCalendar>`.
So in order to compile the signature must be changed into:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(T a) { ... }
```

which is totally understandable. The 1st version of the method effectively doesn't compile in java-5 but it compiles in java-8! (i tried 5 through 8)

Why java-8 now allows that? (because it makes it more confusing now). What's the new "rule" behind that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type inference!

There is a significant amount of information regarding this in [JLS §18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A8693%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C590%2Cnull%5D).  Specifically, I'll direct you to [JLS §18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A8418%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C487%2Cnull%5D) (page 678) which states:

[image]

In your case, let `S = GregorianCalendar` and `T = Calendar`.  This page states (during the reduction process) if `S` is a sub-type of `T`, then `S` is considered to be of type `T` (`GregorianCalendar` is treated as `Calendar`).

Comment: Terminology in JLS §18 is a bit more complex, the contraint formula `‹S <= T›` indicates that _"A type argument S is contained by a type argument T"_  (see [§18.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.2)), not a sub-type relation as the answer indicates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is that you have written

```
min(new GregorianCalendar());
```

as a standalone expression. Prior to Java 8, this would be handled by the compiler by inferring `GregorianCalendar` for `T` which does not fulfill the constraint “`… extends Comparable<T>`”, so it gets rejected.

Starting with Java 8, the compiler infers `Calendar` for `T`, which fulfills the constraint, and it is valid to pass an instance of `GregorianCalendar` where `Calendar` is expected, so the example is accepted. It’s like if you hay written `YourClass.<Calendar>min(new GregorianCalendar());` in previous Java versions.

However, this does not solve the fundamental problem of the `min` declaration that it doesn’t accept `GregorianCalendar` for `T`. While Java 8 allows you to write, e.g.

```
Calendar c = min(new GregorianCalendar());
```

using `Calendar` for `T`, it is still invalid to use `GregorianCalendar` for `T`, e.g.

```
GregorianCalendar c = min(new GregorianCalendar());
```

still will be rejected by the compiler.

Therefore, it is still necessary to use the declaration with wildcard

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(T a) { ... }
```

to allow callers to use it like

```
GregorianCalendar c = min(new GregorianCalendar());
```